# Postgresql - authentication failed in Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

Im trying to run postgresql in my Docker container.

Here is my DockerFile for postgresql

```
FROM postgres:9.5.2

RUN localedef -i ru_RU -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias ru_RU.UTF-8
ENV LANG ru_RU.utf8

ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD OaO1OHrzTZ3cqyLnju2z
ENV PROJECT_USER test
ENV PROJECT_DATABASE test

COPY config/init-user-db.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-user-db.sh
```

init-user-db.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE EXTENSION "adminpack";
    CREATE EXTENSION "autoinc";
    CREATE EXTENSION "cube";
    CREATE EXTENSION "file_fdw";
    CREATE EXTENSION "fuzzystrmatch";
    CREATE EXTENSION "hstore";
    CREATE EXTENSION "insert_username";
    CREATE EXTENSION "intarray";
    CREATE EXTENSION "isn";
    CREATE EXTENSION "lo";
    CREATE EXTENSION "ltree";
    CREATE EXTENSION "moddatetime";
    CREATE EXTENSION "pageinspect";
    CREATE EXTENSION "pgcrypto";
    CREATE EXTENSION "pg_trgm";
    CREATE EXTENSION "postgres_fdw";
    CREATE EXTENSION "refint";
    CREATE EXTENSION "seg";
    CREATE EXTENSION "sslinfo";
    CREATE EXTENSION "tablefunc";
    CREATE EXTENSION "tcn";
    CREATE EXTENSION "timetravel";
    CREATE EXTENSION "unaccent";
    CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
    CREATE EXTENSION "xml2";
    CREATE USER "$PROJECT_USER" WITH password 'OaO1OHrzTZ3cqyLnju2z
';
    CREATE DATABASE "$PROJECT_DATABASE" WITH OWNER="$PROJECT_USER" TEMPLATE=template1 ;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "$PROJECT_DATABASE" TO "$PROJECT_USER";
    REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "$PROJECT_DATABASE" FROM PUBLIC;
EOSQL
```

thats whats in my application configs (symfony 3)

```
parameters:
    database_host: 192.168.99.100
    database_port: 48002
    database_name: test
    database_user: test
    database_password: OaO1OHrzTZ3cqyLnju2z
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: O81s4KSjs8NdxSAacvU82AdC973aSxKdL
```

As you see, i have in every place the same password - OaO1OHrzTZ3cqyLnju2z.

But im getting error password authentication failed for user "test".

What is missing? Why it doesnt authenticate?

Answer (score -1):

Did you paste the script directly from the source? 
Because it looks like you have a space between the last digit on your password and the quote :

```
    CREATE USER "$PROJECT_USER" WITH password 'OaO1OHrzTZ3cqyLnju2z
';
```

Try

```
CREATE USER "$PROJECT_USER" WITH password 'OaO1OHrzTZ3cqyLnju2z';
```

Comment: thats just copy-paste, dont have space there.